# An exception is received [ while trying to load the certificate: Server certificate is invalid ] ]

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works

Good Morning,

So i have this error that you can see in the title when the department of development tries to a sendRequestBillingDocNotification.

We have 3 enviroments, QLT, PRD  and TST. PRD and TST are working fine with the same certificate

Steps that i already made to throubleshoot this error:

- Copy exacly the same certificates that are in the enviroment PRD and TST to QLT.
- Check the BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE that is with the value: [Path of the certificates]

Is there something that i'm not seeing or doing wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the next steps from the tibco documentation:

1. Create a folder in your file system in the location where you wish to store the trusted certificates. You must copy this folder to each machine where your process engines are deployed, or the location can be a shared network area accessible by all process engines.
2. In your TIBCO BusinessWorks project, create a global variable named BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE. See Global Variables for more information about global variables.
3. Set the value of BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE to the location of the trusted certificates folder on your file system. The location can either be the same for all deployed engines (that is, you copied it to the same location on each machine or it is a shared network drive), or you can change the value of the global variable when you deploy the project to the location on the machine where you place the trusted certificates. 
   The value you set for BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE must be a file URL, for example, file:///c:/tibco/certs.
4. You can leave the Trusted Certificates field empty when specifying the trusted certificate location in a SSL Configuration dialog. When the project runs, the value of BW_GLOBAL_CA_STORE overrides any value specified in the Trusted Certificate field.

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/5.11.0-november-2012/doc/pdf/tib_bw_process_design_guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder and put all the certificates which will be used in your EAR/application. (Along with the chain of the certificate)
2. Create a GV named BW_GLOBAL_TRUSTED_CA_STORE at the root level and provide path of the certificate as  **file:///d:/opt/tibco/certs**
3. If you are using a SOAP Request Reply Option , Go to Advance tab and select SSL.